# My app doesn't have 'Translate your app' link

Tags: facebook, translation, locale

I'm trying to translate my app open graph actions, I've searched everywhere and the only thing I read is to click 'Translate your app' link (`http://www.facebook.com/translations/admin/`) and 'Visit translations admin panel' (`https://www.facebook.com/translations/admin/dashboard.php`) but both links doesn't work for me, maybe documentation is old :-/, so I don't know how to access my app translation...

I've found that entering `https://www.facebook.com/translations/admin/dashboard.php?app=[YOUR APP ID]` you can enter the admin dashboard, but all translations are 0% although I have some translated and accepted text, and if it's impossible to access that link from developers section, I think I need to activate something in my app so translations are enabled.

EDIT: The links I see on the left when I edit my app are:

Use Debug Tool - Use Graph API Explorer - See App Timeline View - Promote with an Ad - Eliminar aplicación

I'm lost :-/ Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have to do is to go https://www.facebook.com/translations/admin/dashboard.php?app=[YOUR APP ID]. All the translations are ofcourse at 0% because not translated yet.

1. Go to https://www.facebook.com/translations/admin/dashboard.php?app=[YOUR APP ID]
2. Click on the language you want to translate
3. You'll find text parts you can translate
4. When you are done, check this language (left column) and publish (link in the right column)

P.S.: be aware of a bug, i'm also expieriencing right now. Regardless there are some translations for a language the progress bar can remain 0%.

Comment: So the bar can remain at 0% because of a bug, that's all I needed, it was driving me crazy, I was thinking I was doing something wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Seems that this "bug" still happening, can't believe it

Comment: Yes, the translation part of open graph is very buggy.